# Measuring resistance at every point in multiplex circuit with analog-to-digital IC

Tags: adc, multiplexer

Here I have basic LED multiplex IC (HT16K33). I want to add different resistors in my multiplex circuit and measure them at each x,y position with my ADC IC (ADS1115).

For some reason it won't register any measurements (values oscillate in sine as usual when nothing is attached). I tried with adding another transistor, but without changes. I'm really new in this, so any help appreciated. Is this possible at all, or I have to try different approach?

---

PS. These IC's are as complete modules with all the resistors and capacitors they need to function, I didn't bother to draw them.

---

[image]

Comment: Well, at first sight, it looks like you've connected the cathodes of your LEDs together...

Comment: I think they are supposed to be connected, that's one row of multiplex array. Am I wrong ? At least I can toggle all LED individually.

Comment: First of all, just to be clear, the anode is the part with the triangle, and the cathode is the part with the line. For your top three LEDs, the anodes are connected. For your bottom three diodes (LEDs?), the anodes are connected and the cathodes are connected. The bottom part, assuming it's just a hypothetical redrawing of the upper part, wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You have no physical info in your question , so I conclude you have a noisy SD SC cable picking up line noise. Unless you show how you cabled and grounded this, there no further help, except search my Answers for EMI.